# Local Notification on different dates Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, notifications, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I want to fire the local notification every year on specific dates but all notifications have different title and body , here is my code that I wrote and thats works perfectly but for one notification only and the second part is after getting notification my app icon have 1, means one notification there how to remove this?..

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]){ (allowed, error) in
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        scheduleNotification()
        return true
    }



 func scheduleNotification() {

     var date = DateComponents()
     date.year = 2017
     date.month = 6
     date.day = 12
     date.hour = 22
     date.minute = 39

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: false)
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Schedule Notification"
            content.body = "Today is my Birthday"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            content.badge = 1
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
   }
```

Appreciate and thanks in advance

Comment: You need to schedule multiple notifications; one for each date required.  If you don't want to badge the app icon, don't set the `badge` property

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 so your quick reply..

Answer (score 0):

For repeat notifications you have to schedule multiple notifications. You can do like this.

```
func scheduleNotification(_ title:String, body:String, dateComponents :DateComponents) {        
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = 1
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And use the above function to schedule multiple notifications like this.

```
var date = DateComponents()
date.year = 2017
date.month = 6
date.day = 12
date.hour = 22
date.minute = 39    

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
scheduleNotification("Schedule Notification", body: "Today is my Birthday", dateComponents: date)
scheduleNotification("Schedule Notification 2", body: "Today is my Birthday 2", dateComponents: date2)
scheduleNotification("Schedule Notification 3", body: "Today is my Birthday 3", dateComponents: date3)
```

**Second** part of your question how to remove the badge icon. Add following code somewhere in your applicationDidFinishLaunching or applicationDidBecomeActive.

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: its not working , I create new function called notificationLauncher() and in this function I create three different date components and then I called scheduleNotification function with parameters of title, body and components  and then I called this function in app delegate applicationDidFinisgLaunchingWithOptions :(

Comment: just single notification is working not multiple even when I am trying multiple functions to call multiple notification I am not even getting one notification :(

Comment: are you getting the first notification or the third one ??

Comment: I am not getting any notification when I am trying multiple notifications but when I am trying single notification I am able to get it...

Comment: The above code is not working, this only work for the last schedule date(hour,minute)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a different identifier for every notification gives you the required result.

notificationType - is any String that you can pass while scheduling a notification

`let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Medicine Local Notification\(notificationType)", content: content, trigger: trigger)`